# Insert to wp_footer if widget is found in the sidebar

Tags: widgets

I trying to insert a code into wp_footer whether the widget is present or not in the sidebar.

How to avoid the unnecessary code in the footer?

Add the code only if widget is present the sidebar.

```
 class CustomWidget extends WP_Widget {

   function CustomWidget() { 
     add_action( 'wp_footer', array($this,'footer'), 10, 1 );   
   }

   function widget($args, $instance) { }

   function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {}

   function form($instance) {}

   function footer {
      $all_widgets = $this->get_settings();

      foreach ($all_widgets as $key => $wpdcjqverticalmegamenu){

       $widget_id = $this->id_base . '-' . $key;

      if(is_active_widget(false, $widget_id, $this->id_base)){

      }     

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of widget is called when the widget is registered, so your `add_action` is called on (probably) every request. You can avoid that simply put the `add_action` inside `widget()` function, that is called only when the widget is printed so there is no need to check: just output what you want.

Also, if you need some context inside the `footer` method you can use a closure inside the `widget` method where you have easy access to `$args` and `$instance` variables (the first contain information about the sidebar and the widget id, the second contain informations on the fields setted for speficic widget):

```
class CustomWidget extends WP_Widget {

   function __construct() { 
      parent::__construct( 'my-widget-id', 'My Widget Name' );
   }

   function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    add_action( 'wp_footer', function() use ( $args, $instance ) {

      echo '<h1>' . $args['widget_id'] . '</h1>';
      echo '<pre>'; print_r( $instance ); echo '</pre>';
      echo '<pre>'; print_r( $args); echo '</pre>';
      echo '<hr>';

    }); 

   }

   function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {}

   function form($instance) {}

}
```

that makes the closure all the times the widget is added to page, i.e. if the widget is added 3 times, the closure will run 3 times.

If you want to prevent that use a static flag:

```
class CustomWidget extends WP_Widget {

   static $added = 0;

   function __construct() { 
      parent::__construct( 'my-widget-id', 'My Widget Name' );
   }

   function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    add_action( 'wp_footer', function() use ( $args, $instance ) {

      if ( static::$added !== 0 ) return; // run only once;
      static::$added++;

      echo '<h1>' . $args['widget_id'] . '</h1>';
      echo '<pre>'; print_r( $instance ); echo '</pre>';
      echo '<pre>'; print_r( $args); echo '</pre>';
      echo '<hr>';

    }); 

   }

   function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {}

   function form($instance) {}

}
```

<sup>PS: PHP 4 died a long time ago. Please use [PHP 5 constructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)...</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to save all  the added widgets id in an array() instead of count. How to get the widget base id?

Comment: Why do you want to save that in an array? @BLPraveen

Comment: I have modified the footer function. you can check the current function which gets all the widget matching the baseid. Hence I asked if I can get the widget base ids stored in the array

Comment: I need to check type in the instance based on that I select differnt codes to insert

Comment: Is it possible to get the widget id?

Comment: @GM Thanks it add to the footer what is required and avoids unnecessary code

Comment: _construct function is not used and when I use get unexpected output.

Comment: @BLPraveen `__construct` have 2 underscores. And you need to call `parent::__construct` inside it, like I do. What you are doing is just use the PHP4 version of constructor, nothing different.